# How to use LazyLoader and PullToRefresh in recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, lazy-loading, pull-to-refresh

**WHY NOT ANY PEOPLE HELP ME??? i really need your helps**

In my application i want use **PullToRefresh** and **LazyLoader** features and for this i write below codes and work me.

But i have one issue, when **PullToRefresh** `recyclerView` and when scroll `recyclerView` not show more items.

My mean is : when use **pullToRefresh**, then not work **lazyLoader**!

**My codes :**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        Constants.listeners.add(this);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auction_current_tab, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        context = getActivity();
        handler = new Handler();
        list = v.findViewById(R.id.list);
        prefsUtils = new PrefsUtils(getActivity());
        apis = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIs.class);
        swipeToRefresh = v.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);

        jwtToken = Constants.settings.getString("jwt_token", "");

        list_item = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        auctionListAdapter = new AuctionsListAdapter(context, todayModel, R.layout.list_item_auction_normal_new);
        list.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        list.setAdapter(auctionListAdapter);
        list.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerLinearPage(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(final int current_page) {
                miniLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Call<AuctionsListResponse> call = apis.getTodatAuctions(jwtToken, current_page, 10);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<AuctionsListResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AuctionsListResponse> call, Response<AuctionsListResponse> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (response.body() != null) {
                                if (response.body().getRes() != null) {
                                    if (response.body().getRes().getToday().size() > 0 && response.body().getRes().getToday() != null) {
                                        miniLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        auctionListAdapter.addNewItem(response.body().getRes().getToday());
                                    } else {
                                        miniLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AuctionsListResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        getData();
        swipeToRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorAccent);
        swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                getData();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    private void getData() {
        Call<AuctionsListResponse> call = apis.getTodatAuctions(jwtToken, 1, 10);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<AuctionsListResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AuctionsListResponse> call, Response<AuctionsListResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        if (response.body().getRes() != null) {
                            if (response.body().getRes().getToday().size() > 0 && response.body().getRes().getToday() != null) {
                                todayModel.clear();
                                todayModel.addAll(response.body().getRes().getToday());
                                auctionListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                itemsLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (swipeToRefresh != null) {
                                    swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AuctionsListResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Dr Kong: you were already told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780788/how-to-use-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore-in-recyclerview#comment88568293_50780788) that you shouldn't **SHOUT** at people, weren't you? do you really think that you receive any answer if the only change in your question is a nick change?

Comment: @pskink, ok and excuse me dear, but not any people help me? i need help :(

Comment: People help if they can and if they notice your question, you really shouldn't cry about it in the first line of your question.

Comment: Can you explain to me what are you achieving? Your question is confusing. Refresh using `SwipeRefreshLayout`? And which part doesn't work? It throws Exception? Data doesn't get updated?

Comment: @YosiPramajaya, yes for use pullToRefresh i used `SwipeRefreshLayout` , when use pullToRefresh get updated data and not issue with update data. but when use pullToRefresh when scroll on recycler and receive to end list then not work lazyLoader! can you help me? please

Comment: @YosiPramajaya, are you here my friend? can you help me? please

Comment: Still trying to comprehend your question. What does it mean when you said: then not work lazyLoader? You mean it doesn't work? When? When you scroll more, when you pull to refresh, or both? 

What is lazyLoader, you mean the async retrofit call?

Comment: @YosiPramajaya. when use pullToRefresh then not work lazy loader. my mean is when use pullToRefresh when when receive last item of recyclerView not work lazyLoader

Comment: @Hock Show me your code for `AuctionsListAdapter`

Comment: @YosiPramajaya. i uploaded in this link : https://ufile.io/lz1mr can you help me? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your `getData()` method.

Why? When you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from your `RecyclerView.Adapter`, it tells your adapter to check again the list that it has, and fully rebind and redraw everything in `RecyclerView`. But the thing is, in your `getData()` you only set `todayModel` List which is an object reference **inside your Fragment**.

Therefore, you need to modify the list **inside your Adapter** in order to make successful `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Actually, what you did in your `onLoadMore()` is correct where you modify the List **inside** your Adapter. You should do the same (or similar) thing in your `getData()`.

Sample code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    Constants.listeners.add(this);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auction_current_tab, null);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    context = getActivity();
    handler = new Handler();
    list = v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    prefsUtils = new PrefsUtils(getActivity());
    apis = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIs.class);
    swipeToRefresh = v.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);

    jwtToken = Constants.settings.getString("jwt_token", "");

    list_item = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    auctionListAdapter = new AuctionsListAdapter(context, todayModel, R.layout.list_item_auction_normal_new);
    list.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    list.setAdapter(auctionListAdapter);
    list.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerLinearPage(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(final int current_page) {
            miniLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            getData(currentPage);
        }
    });
    getData(1);
    swipeToRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorAccent);
    swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            getData(1);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

private void getData(int page) {
    Call<AuctionsListResponse> call = apis.getTodatAuctions(jwtToken, page, 10);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AuctionsListResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AuctionsListResponse> call, Response<AuctionsListResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    if (response.body().getRes() != null) {
                        if (response.body().getRes().getToday().size() > 0 && response.body().getRes().getToday() != null) {
                            todayModel.clear();
                            todayModel
                                 .addAll(response.body()
                                                 .getRes()
                                                 .getToday());

                            //NOTICE THE DIFFERENCE HERE
                            auctionListAdapter.setModel(todayModel);
                            auctionListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            itemsLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (swipeToRefresh != null) {
                                swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                            }
                            miniLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AuctionsListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
             itemsLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             if (swipeToRefresh != null) {
                swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
             }
             miniLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

In your `AuctionsListAdapter` add this method. It is to set up the list that will be used by the Adapter to show the data:

```
public void setModel(List<Today> todayModel) {
    this.model = todayModel;
}
```

Comment: Can you send to me code with my codes? please. i am amateur and really need your help. please

Comment: are you here my friend? can you help me? please

Comment: Why not answered to me my friend? :D

Comment: You should know that most of us have real life here, that's why we can't be 24 hours watching the threads. Be patience please.

Comment: Can you my friend for your help, but what code is for this line : `auctionListAdapter.setModel(todayModel);` what add code to adapter for use `setModel` code ?

Comment: It's actually just setter. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for update. in `onLoadMore` you use `getData();` , and into this code : `apis.getTodatAuctions(jwtToken, 1, 10)`; **1** is page number but in `onLoadMore` should get data from **other pages**. when use `getData` in `onLoadMore` every time show items from **page 1**. how can i fix it?

Comment: You can edit to become `getData(int page)`. And when you invoke `getData()` you can give whatever page you want as parameter.

Comment: Can you send to me your skype ID? please

Comment: Why? You can always ask here, and I'm sure there are a lot of other professionals will help you out. :) And your questions might help other developers to learn and study